# Android: How to send an ics File to apps on the Phone

Tags: java, android, calendar, icalendar, android-implicit-intent

I am creating an .ics File in my Activity. I want to send the created .ics File to a calendar app on the phone, so the app can import the events.

Here is my code for the Intent:

```
`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALENDAR);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(icsfile));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "How do you want to share?"));`
```

Unfortunately no calender apps are shown in the chooser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Calendar, at least, does not support responding to `ACTION_SEND`.

So, try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(icsfile), "application/ics");
startActivity(intent);
```

(and, eventually, switch to using `FileProvider` as opposed to `Uri.fromFile()`, as that does not work on Android 7.0+ for apps with a `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or higher)